Solution-verification: Solve $3x^2-6x+4 = 6\{x\}\bigl(\lfloor x\rfloor - \{x\}\bigr)$
the problem

Solve in the set of real numbers the following equation
$$
3x^2-6x+4 = 6\{x\}\bigl(\lfloor x\rfloor - \{x\}\bigr),
$$
where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ and $\{x\}$ are the whole part and the fractional part, respectively, of the real number $x$.

my idea
First of all I noted $a = \lfloor x\rfloor,\, b=\{x\},\, x = a+b$.
The the equation becomes
$$
\begin{aligned} 
&& 3(a+b)^2 - 6a - 6b + 4 &= 6b(a-b) \\
\implies && 3a^2 + 3b^2 + 6ab - 6a - 6b + 4 &= 6ab - 6b^2 \\
\implies && 3a^2 + 9b^2 - 6a - 6b + 4 &= 0 \\
\implies && 3(a-1)^2 + (3b-1)^2 &= 0. 
\end{aligned}
$$
Because the perfect squares are always positive, we have
$$
a - 1 = 0 \implies a=1
$$
and
$$
3b - 1 = 0 \implies b = \tfrac{1}{3}. 
$$
I put this as a solution-verification because I'm not sure if I can note the whole part, respectively the fractional part of the real number $x$ with $a$ and $b$ and work with them as normal real numbers. Also I'm not sure if there are any cases I omitted.
Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

@peterwhy Nope, it means rounding towards $-infty$

The solution seems perfectly fine to me. As long as you don't get values outside of $[0; 1)$ for $b$, it all seems okay.

I think he means the floor function. Then only $x = {x} + [x] $, for ceil its $x= [x]-{x}$. The only question is, does this have another root, as it is quadratic but with restriction, $a, b \in \mathbb{Z} \times [0,1)$.

Solution seems fine to me. As mentioned you must remember $b \in [0; 1)$ and $a \in \mathbb{Z}$

Treat the a, b equation as a conic section. See what type of object it is, easier to spot the roots.

As long as a comes out an integer and b in range [0,1) our assumptions hold true and so the answer is good to go. Solution is perfectly fine as if a didn't ended up and integer or b was not in the specified range we could have easily concluded that there are no solutions

Lets try the common way: $n\leq x<n+1.$ Then $\lfloor x\rfloor=n$ and $\{x\}=x-n.$ Putting in the equation we get
$$3x^2-6x+4=6(x-n)(2n-x)$$
$$3x^2-6x+4=-6x^2+18nx-12n^2$$
$$(3x-4)^2=12-18x+18nx-12n^2$$
$$(3x-4)^2=6(n-1)(3x-2)$$
$$(3x-4)^2-6(n-1)(3x-4)=12(n-1)$$
$$(3x-4-3n+3)^2=12(n-1)+9(n-1)^2$$
$$(3x-3n-1)^2=9n^2-6n-3$$
$$(3x-3n-1)^2+4=(3n-1)^2$$
Since $0\leq3x-3n<3$, we have $4\leq(3n-1)^2<8.$ So, $n$ can only be $1$ with $x=\frac43.$

I think it's accepted that the algebraic calculations once you substitute $x=a+b$ are valid so let's talk about why you can make this substitution.
Most steps in solving equations are "if and only if", bidirectional, as they can be reversed e.g. adding an expression to both sides (reversed by subtraction). $x+y=9\iff x+y+1=10$.
You either get extraneous or missing solutions only if the implication goes only one way. For instance, when using the positive square root you get missing solutions because the implication only goes backwards ($x^2=4\impliedby x=2$). When multiplying by 0 you get extraneous solutions because the implication only goes forward ($3x=12\implies 0=0$).
When you say $a = \lfloor x\rfloor$, $b=\{x\}$, the only risk is extraneous solutions because you are ignoring (for the time being) the requirements that are something like $a\in \mathbb{Z},b\in [0, 1)$ (depending on what exactly "fractional part" of a negative number means). The implication works forwards: $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is a real number (call it $a$), but not every real number $a$ could be equal to $\lfloor x\rfloor$.
By checking your solutions are valid in the original equation and context, you discover whether the solutions were extraneous or genuine. The logic has proceeded $3x^2-6x+4 = 6\{x\}\bigl(\lfloor x\rfloor - \{x\})\implies x=4/3$ and then you substitute to check $x=4/3\implies 3x^2-6x+4 = 6\{x\}\bigl(\lfloor x\rfloor - \{x\})$. Thus you have provably found all solutions.

+1 : "You either get extraneous or missing solutions if the implication goes only one way." - very nice, but somewhat inaccurate and misleading.  You can not get missing solutions.  Also, you may or may not get extraneous solutions.  For example $~x = 2 \implies x^2 = 4,~$ which has the two solutions $~-2, +2.~$  So, it is not possible for the $~x = +2~$ solution to be missing.

I've changed it to "You either get extraneous or missing solutions only if the implication goes only one way", somewhat ironically.

I disagree.  Assuming that the implication goes only one way, you will still not get missing solutions.

So in the case $x^2=4\impliedby x=2$...? If you have extraneous solutions when you read forwards to backwards then you have missing solutions when you read backwards to forwards.

When the original poster reads your answer, and reads that if the implication only goes one way, there are missing solutions, how are they going to interpret this?  I interpreted it to signify that you are mistaken.  I suggest that you abandon the forwards to backwards and backwards to forwards ideas, and instead focus on if the implication only goes one way, then the solutions to the implied equation must contain the solutions to the original equation.  I think that this approach will be less confusing to the original poster.
